# Django polls app is not working as expctected in the tutorial for me

Tags: django

I am getting this error every time restart my server

> Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
>
> Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order:  admin/  The current path, polls/, didn't
>   match any of these.

I have tried restarting the server but the same error is popping up every time.

**polls/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),

]
```

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [

    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),

    path("admin/", admin.site.urls)

]
```

**views.py/polls**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):

    return HttpResponse("Hello world. You're at the polls index.")
```

The expected result as per the Django tutorial is the text "Hello world. You're at the polls index." after you start your server

Comment: You didn't add polls  to installed apps in your settings.py

Comment: Also, I recommend the Django Girls tutorial which is much more accessible to beginners  - https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't add your app polls to installed apps in your settings.py.

Open your file `settings.py` and write:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...., 
'polls',

]
```